# Is it possible to render a react class when given its name as a string?

Tags: reactjs

Here's a smaller example of what I'm trying to do, I don't know if it's possible to do something similar or I should use an entirely different method.

```
import {Design1, Design2} from './page-designs';

let designs = {
"page1":"Design1",
"page2":"Design2",
"page3":"Design1",
"page4":"Design2"
}

class DesignedPage extends React.Component {
    let Design = designs[this.props.page]
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="row flex-fill d-flex">
                <div className="col-1"></div>
                     <Design /* This is the line that fails */
                      data = {this.props.data}
                     />
                </div>
            </div>
    )}
}

class Main extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <DesignedPage
               page = {this.props.openPage} /*this could be any of page1-4 depending on button a click*/
               data = {this.props.data}
              />
    )}
}
```

Ideally this would render the react elements Design1 or Design2 based on what props.page is passed, but instead it returns
`"Warning: <Design1 /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements."` and `"The tag <Design1> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter."`

I've thought of making a long if, elseif, elseif.. statement in DesignedPage (the actual code has many more than 2 designs), which I'm fairly confident would work, but looks very messy in comparison.

Comment: See: [Choosing the Type at Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render the component name by getting its name as a string. You need to map the string to the component iteself:

```
let designs = {
  "page1":Design1,
  "page2":Design2,
}
```

Comment: Oh my god that was so easy I've been stuck on this for hours!! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, if this answer helped you I would appreciate if you mark it as the answer :) Happy coding

Comment: You've answered so fast it won't let me accept an answer yet, I'll accept it as soon as I'm allowed

Comment: Hahah, no problem! Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a string, react would think it's a HTML tag, hence it say'Design1' tag is unrecognised. Also, you could import the components and use them as values in the designs object in place of strings.

```
let designs = {
"page1":Design1,
"page2":Design2,
"page3":Design1,
"page4":Design2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make one function that return react component..

```
getComponent = ({data, pageName}) => {
  if(pageName === "page1") return <Desig1 />;
  if(pageName === "page2") return <Design2 />;
}
```

and call function from render of DesignedPage component

const {page, data} = this.props;

```
 return(
    <div className="row flex-fill d-flex">
        <div className="col-1">
         {getComponent(page, data)}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
```